# Optimising Java Script code

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this JavaScript code to add and remove some classes. Below is the code. Can anybody help me to optimize this code?

```
  $(".showTR").click(function () {
    if (!$(this).parent().parent('tr').next('tr').hasClass('Row')) {
        if (!$(this).parent().parent('tr').next('tr').next('tr').hasClass('Row')) {
            if (!$(this).parent().parent('tr').next('tr').next('tr').next('tr').hasClass('Row')) {
                if (!$(this).parent().parent('tr').next('tr').next('tr').next('tr').next('tr').hasClass('Row')) {
                    if (!$(this).parent().parent('tr').next('tr').next('tr').next('tr').next('tr').next('tr').hasClass('Row')) {
                        if (!$(this).parent().parent('tr').next('tr').next('tr').next('tr').next('tr').next('tr').next('tr').hasClass('Row')) {

                        } else {
                            $(this).parent().parent('tr').next('tr').next('tr').next('tr').next('tr').next('tr').next('tr').removeClass('Row')
                            $(this).hide();
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        $(this).parent().parent('tr').next('tr').next('tr').next('tr').next('tr').next('tr').removeClass('Row');
                    }
                } else {
                    $(this).parent().parent('tr').next('tr').next('tr').next('tr').next('tr').removeClass('Row');
                }

            } else {
                $(this).parent().parent('tr').next('tr').next('tr').next('tr').removeClass('Row');
            }
        } else {
            $(this).parent().parent('tr').next('tr').next('tr').removeClass('Row');
        }
    }
    else {
        $(this).parent().parent('tr').next('tr').removeClass('Row');          
    }

});
```

The code tries to detect tables next `tr` has class `Row` or not. If not then it goes to next `tr`, if yes it removes class `Row` from next `tr` then goes to next `tr` and so on ...

Comment: Can you provide some example where this scenario exists? ie.., fiddle

Comment: You can start by saving `$(this).parent().parent('tr').next('tr')` in a variable

Comment: Make an `array` of all `tr` tags that contain the class `Row`. Then iterate through the `array` and remove the classes from the elements in the odd indices of the `array`. Isn't that what you are essentially ending up doing?

Comment: Maybe this might be more suited to codereview.stackexchange.com...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since HTML code is not available, you can try something like this:

**Approach 1**

- Navigate to parent `tr`, For this you can use `.closest('tr')` or `.parents('tr')`
- Now get the list of all next `tr`s using `.nextAll('tr')`
- Loop over them and check every value. If it has class, remove it and update a flag to not affect other trs.
- If it was last `tr`, also hide `.showTR`

```js
$(".showTR").click(function() {
  var self = this;
  var hasUpdated = false;
  var trs = $(this).parents('tr').nextAll("tr");
  $.each(trs, function(i, tr) {
    if (!hasUpdated) {
      var $tr = $(tr);
      hasUpdated = $tr.hasClass('Row') && $tr.removeClass('Row') && true;
      if (i === trs.length - 1) {
        $(self).hide()
      }
    }
  })
});
```

---

**Approach 2**

- Get first sibling `tr` to parent `tr` that has class "Row".
- Remove class from it.
- If it is last child, hide `.showTR`

```js
$(".showTR").click(function() {
  var tr = $(this).parents('tr').next("tr.Row:first");
  if(tr.length){
    tr.removeClass("Row");
    if(tr.is(':last-child'))
      $(this).hide()
  }
});
```

Comment: **Note:** This answer is just compressed versions of code shared by OP. If there is any issues, please comment it along with your vote

Comment: Its always going to find next tr.My condition is that if .showTR's next tr dont ave class "Row" then find next tr and so on. we are just finding next tr here.I think we need to loop through tr coming after .showTR class.Can we do this?

Comment: No need Approach 1 work perfectly.Thanks such a great logic.